# Mark Seams Not Fixing Mesh

Tags: uv, seams

I'm trying to understand why this selection of my mesh is not one continuous piece of UV? I've re-marked the seams and unwrapped it and it doesn't seem to help.

[image]

Comment: The image you've posted is too small to make out any details. Use Blender's built-in method via Window > Save Screenshot and post that instead. Could also you please share your file so that we can see what's going on? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @JohnEason The file was too large to upload so you can find it here: https://we.tl/t-mxJakZtPJD. I thought I captured everything necessary in the screenshot.

Comment: I assume that's an asset imported from some other software as it's all triangulated and also had around 1800 overlapping vertices. To be honest, I'm not sure you're ever going to be able to unwrap it successfully in Blender.